# reformat a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working on this for a while I have dataframe that looks like this

```
tables      columns
tab1        col001
tab1        col002    
tab1        col003 
tab2        col01 
tab2        col02  
tab2        col03
```

the real one has 1500 total tables, some column names are duplicated and the entire thing is 80,000 rows by 2 columns, I am trying to get it formatted like this

```
tables      columns
tab1        col001,col002,col003
tab2        col01,col02,col03
```

I tried a crosstab like so

```
cross_table = pd.crosstab(df['tables'], 
                      df['columns']).fillna('n/a')
```

but that's not exactly what I am going for it ends up with all columns as 1's and 0's and is a large sparse matrix

I also tried this, but the error of allocating 2 GiB makes me think this is incorrect

```
df.pivot(columns=['tables', 'columns'], values=['columns'])
```

I also tried pandas melt but that doesn't seem right either

then I tried to cast the columns to a list like so

```
cols = list(df['columns'].unique())

df['cols'] = df['columns'].str.findall(f'({"|".join(cols)})')
```

I tried that because it worked before for extracting text, but in a different context, as it is written it just splits each column name into individual characters

Comment: `df.groupby('tables').agg({'columns': ','.join}).reset_index()`

Comment: this works, i did not spend enough time googling pandas group by with a string as the agg function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### SETUP:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'tables': {0: 'tab1', 1: 'tab1', 2: 'tab1', 3: 'tab2', 4: 'tab2', 5: 'tab2'},
 'columns': {0: 'col001',
  1: 'col002',
  2: 'col003',
  3: 'col01',
  4: 'col02',
  5: 'col03'}})
```

#### 1. via `groupby`:

```
df = df.groupby('tables').agg(', '.join).reset_index() # Almost same as the answer in the post's comment section via @Psidom
```

#### 2. via `pivot_table`:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index = 'tables', values = 'columns', aggfunc = ', '.join).reset_index()
```

#### 3. via `list comprehension`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(i, ', '.join(df[df['tables'] == i]['columns']))
                   for i in df['tables'].unique()], columns=df.columns)
```

#### 4. `Set_index/unstack` option:

```
df = df.set_index('tables', append = True).unstack(0).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna()), 1).reset_index(name = 'columns')
```

#### 5. via `pd.get_dummies`

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df.tables).mul(df['columns'], 0).agg(', '.join).str.strip(
    ', ').reset_index(name='columns').rename({'index': 'tables'})
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
  tables                 columns
0   tab1  col001, col002, col003
1   tab2     col01, col02, col03
```

Comment: I don't know about you guys, but this looks almost exactly like Psidom's comment

Comment: this works, i did not spend enough time googling pandas group by with a string as the agg function

Comment: he posted it 5 mins ago but you posted it 3 mins ago

Comment: @Theshape Added another option via `pivot_table`. I guess this is different now :)

Comment: :D but what you should do is you should put "some refrence from Psidom" beside your first question, but other than that, Your new answer looks great :P